# Why is the addr variable type-converted?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

While surfing on the internet I've found a c++ example that sends GET-requests. The part of this code I couldn't grasp is why (see the section that's bold) the variable addr is type converted. I understand that the function only accepts a certain type. But why using a type and then converting it to another one?

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <resolv.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()

{
    int s, error;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if((s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        cout<<"Error 01: creating socket failed!\n";
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_aton("204.27.61.92",&addr.sin_addr);
```

error = connect(s,(**sockaddr*)&addr**,sizeof(addr));

```
    if(error!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Error 02: conecting to server failed!\n";
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

    char msg[] = "GET /beej/inet_ntoaman.html http/1.1\nHOST: retran.com\n\n";
    char answ[1024];
    //cin.getline(&msg[0],256);

    send(s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);

    while(recv(s,answ,1024,0)!=0)
        cout<<answ<<endl;

    close(s);
    cin.getline(&msg[0],1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `connect()` need `sockaddr` type as the argument. As shown here, `int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);`

Comment: I get that, but why define a port etc and then change the struct so that it doesn't hold those information anymore. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You may be missing the fact that there are multiple socket address families, requiring different information, but all using the same group of functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is runtime polymorphism, C style.

`sockaddr` is effectively an abstract base class - it isn't specific to any concrete type of socket. However, each socket type requires type-specific information.

Since C doesn't have language support for polymorphism, the technique is to write a "derived" type which has the "base" type as it's first data member. This way they have the same address, and you can cast between them.

So, `(sockaddr*)&addr` is an upcast, yielding a pointer to a valid base-class subobject. When you pass this to an AF_INET socket, it will cast the pointer back to `(sockaddr_in*)` and recover your inet-specific data.

---

Equivalent C++ for reference, since it's slightly more expressive:

```
class SockAddr {
public:
  virtual ~SockAddr();
  enum Family { INET, UNIX, ... };
  Family get_family() const { return family; }
protected:
  explicit SockAddr(Family f) : family(f) {}
  Family family;
};

class SockAddrInet: public SockAddr {
  uint16_t port;
  uint32_t addr;
public:
  SockAddrInet(uint16_t port, uint32_t addr)
   : SockAddr(SockAddr::INET), port(htons(port)), addr(addr)
  {}
};    

class SockAddrUnix: public SockAddr {
  std::string path;
public:
  explicit SockAddrInet(std::string path)
   : SockAddr(SockAddr::UNIX), path(path) {}
};

void connect(Socket &s, SockAddr const &addr) {
  switch (addr.get_family()) {
  case SockAddr::INET:
    connect_inet(s, dynamic_cast<SockAddrInet const&>(addr));
    break;
  case SockAddr::UNIX:
    connect_unix(s, dynamic_cast<SockAddrUnix const&>(addr));
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a technique to have "subtypes" in C. There are various other `sockaddr` types (e.g. `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6). The called function inspects the `sin_family` field to determine which kind of struct was passed in and handle it accordingly.

Comment: I get that, but why define a port etc and then change the struct so that it doesn't hold those information anymore. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It's not being changed. The pointer is being cast, but all the same information is still in memory. `connect` will cast it back down to `sockaddr_in` based on the fact that `sin_family` is `AF_INET`.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct sockaddr {
    u_short sa_family;
    char    sa_data[14];
};
```

We have to remember that the socket APIs can work with many different network protocols. Each protocol has a completely different format for how addresses work. This `sockaddr` structure is, therefore, **a generic structure**. It contains a place to put the identifying address family, along with a generic "data" field that the address can be placed in, regardless of the format of the address.

There is however the `sockaddr_in` structure:

```
     struct sockaddr_in {            /* socket address (internet)   */
         short  sin_family;          /* address family (AF_INET)    */
       u_short  sin_port;            /* port number                 */
        struct  in_addr  sin_addr;   /* IP address                  */
          char  sin_zero[8];         /* reserved - must be 0x00's   */
     };
```

which is designed specially for networking, IP address. This type can be safely type casted to `sockaddr*` because it is aligned to it.

This is what Richard Stevens says about it in his "UNIX Network Programming":

### Generic Socket Address Structure

A socket address structures is *always* passed by reference when passed as an argument to
any socket functions. But any socket function that takes one of these pointers as an
argument must deal with socket address structures from *any* of the supported protocol
families.
A problem arises in how to declare the type of pointer that is passed. With ANSI C, the
solution is simple: `void *` is the generic pointer type. But, the socket functions predate ANSI C and the solution chosen in 1982 was to define a **generic socket address structure** in the `<sys/socket.h>` header (...)

```
struct sockaddr {
    uint8_t     sa_len;
    sa_family_t sa_family;    /* address family: AF_xxx value */
    char        sa_data[14];  /* protocol-specific address */
};
```

The socket functions are then defined as taking a pointer to the generic socket address
structure, as shown here in the ANSI C function prototype for the bind function:

```
int bind(int, struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
```

This requires that **any calls to these functions must cast the pointer to the protocol-specific socket address structure to be a pointer to a generic socket address structure**. (...)
From the kernel's perspective, another reason for using pointers to generic socket address
structures as arguments is that the kernel must take the caller's pointer, cast it to a `struct sockaddr *`, and then look at the value of `sa_family` to determine the type of the structure.
But from an application programmer's perspective, it would be simpler if the pointer type was `void *`, omitting the need for the explicit cast.

Comment: You have it a bit backwards. `sockaddr` is for sockets generically. `sockaddr_in` is for IP, and there are other types for other (non-IP) protocols.

Comment: well this is exactly what I said

Comment: Your wording is not clear - you say "IP address" immediately after showing the generic `sockaddr` struct, and say that `sockaddr_in` is "specially for networking (which is *technically* true, but the point is that `sockaddr_in` is for IP).

Answer (score -1):

Returning to the windows's connect function ::connect

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It requires sockaddr as a parameter type

Comment: I get that, but why define a port etc and then change the struct so that it doesn't hold those information anymore. Am I missing something ?